# Allowing role permissions to a content type based on the date

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I'd like to allow a certain role can add new content of a certain content-type ONLY between two dates. Before or after these dates the role shouldn't be able to create a new content of this content-type.

Is it possible through the Drupal core or any module? I haven't found anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement [hook_node_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) (This is now a real hook in Drupal 7) and implement whatever you want.

Comment: Mmmm, It sounds great. I hadn't thought about this hook. Nevertheless, I would have to create some frontend to save the date interval and role affected. I don't want to edit ".module" file every time. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but you will have to do that whatever way you implement the access check.

Comment: I've created a "date field" in my content-type with a default value (maximum date for which an user has permissions to add new content for this content-type). The problem is I can't access to this field from "hook_node_access". Furthermore, this value is encrypted in database and I can't do a db_query to retrieve this value. Any suggestions?